# UIWebView scrollview versus no scrollview Memory

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am currently working on an ios7 project that uses uiwebview. There seems to be large memory usage occurring with the use of uiwebivews, mainly we open a new view with a webview for reading mobile html news articles.

We are trying to improve the memory management as it seems that the app hits the "closed due to memory pressure"

I have implemented the memory leak prevention outlined here: http://www.codercowboy.com/code-uiwebview-memory-leak-prevention/

My question though is there a difference in memory usage when using the scrollview to scroll down the content versus just having the uiwebview's frame be the size of the content for a view?

We are currently not using the scrollview and just showing the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding a UIWebView inside a UIScrollView shouldn't make any memory usage differences at all.  Are you sure this is a webview issue?  Have you tried making a simple app only containing a webview and pointing it at your page and seeing what happens?  You may be leaking/wasting memory elsewhere in your app that needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: its possible, memory spikes only when are start opening views with uiwebview, its not using the uiwebview's scrollview i am setting the frame's height to the content so its not using the scroll that comes generally with uiwebview.

Comment: Do you have a lot of images on your page?  I am pretty certain that UIWebVIew loads content like that as you scroll.  Like I said before, you need to try eliminating variables until you no longer have crashing issues.  Another thing you could try is just tell your webview to load "http://www.google.com" and see if that causes any problems.  Also, note what your memory usage is before you do this and after you do this.  Then do the same for loading your own content.  If that fails you, you may want to try my original suggestion of making a super simple app and seeing if it runs out of memory.